# Views exposed filter and non latin characters

Tags: 7, views

I have a combined text box exposed filter of a view. Is there any way that I can alter the keywords used by the user to convert non-latin characters to latin using hook_views_query_alter?

Answer (score 0):

[Transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module has some useful functions to convert unicode strings into latin strings. You may give it a try and use some of those functions in your alter hooks. I cannot give you a specific function name but I'm sure that I've used this module for a similar purpose.

Anyway, if you work with non-latin languages, you'll probably need to install this module for other purposes, like fixing the filenames and url parts generated by user input etc.

A quick look-up into the source code of Transliteration module, I can say that you can use `transliteration_get()` function to transliterate a give string. A sample implementation for your case would be:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  // To debug comment out the following line (Devel module is required).
  //dpm($query);

  if ($view->name = 'YOUR_VIEW' && !empty($view->exposed_raw_input['YOUR_FIELD']) {
    $transliterated = transliteration_get($view->exposed_raw_input['YOUR_FIELD']);
    // Traverse through the 'where' part of the query.
    foreach ($query->where as &$condition_group) {
      foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as &$condition) {
        // If this is the part of the query filtering on your field, change the
        // condition value to the transliterated string.
        if ($condition['field'] == 'YOUR FIELD') {
          $condition['value'] = $transliterated;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it came to my mind that somehow I need to incorporate this module but I would love some specifics. Though reading through the readme file I guess the only function that I can use is this function_exists('transliteration_get')

Comment: yes, I had a quick look into the source code, and I can say that you can use this function to transliterate a string.

Comment: I've add a sample code to show how to use this function in a hook implementation

Comment: I guess this is more that enough help I can get. Thanks. One more thing though...my search box is a combined filter. Which 'YOUR FIELD' I must use?

Comment: I cannot know what fields are in your views defined. But you can use some debugging to find out the fields. If you don't have any debug setup like XDebug or so, I recommend the [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module. After enabling Devel module, you can use `dpm($query)` to print out whole query object and inspect what conditions and fields are defined.

Comment: I've added a commented out line to show how to print out the debug information. After putting this line, reload the page with the view, and you'll see a debug output on the messages area of the page.
P.S.: If my answer helped, please upvote and accept.

Comment: OK...I am on to try your suggections. Please let me check your solution and implement on my use case and I would get back here.